# SQLite Connection Opens but Can't Read Data, Code Execution Stops

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, connection, command

I've been at this for a couple of days ladies and gentlemen and I can't figure it out.  I have an application where I open a connection to a SQLite DB and select some data out of a table.  The connection opens fine.  As soon as I attempt to read the data via an SQLiteDataAdapter or an SQLiteCommand object using ExecuteReader, my code appears to just stop executing as if it reached the last statement.  There are no exceptions, nothing in the EventViewer, etc.  It just acts like it reached the end of the code and the program is idle.

I found [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1350c0ac-7e83-41cc-8df8-11318e3c28ee/code-stops-executing-at-dataadapterfill-line?forum=csharpgeneral) that is pretty much the same behavior I'm experiencing.

Some brief info on what I've done:

- I've installed the SQLite 32bit and 64bit binaries.
- I tried setting my CPU type to x86 while using the 32bit SQLite binaries
- I tried setting my CPU type to x64 while using the 64bit SQLite binaries
- I tried using adapter.Fill(), code just stops
- I tried using command.ExecuteReader(), code just stops
- If I don't open the connection before ExecuteReader(), it bombs, indicating the connection isn't open so it at least is able to communicate and know what SQLite is, right?

My code:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection
    ("Data Source=" + srcFile + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
SQLiteDataReader reader = null;

command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "select * from stuff";

try
{
    connection.Open();
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();  //<-- CODE APPEARS TO BREAK OUT OF EXECUTION

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }

    // Close/Dispose of Connection
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log error...
    // Close/Dispose of Connection
}
```

Like I said, the code just stops executing right when command.ExecuteReader() is executed or when I was doing the adapter.Fill()...the program is still running, just no more code execution so the reader.Read() is never reached.

Comment: And if you remove the try/catch what happens in that case?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the behaviour in a short but complete console app, or does it depend on other aspects of your app?

Comment: Super fast replies people, thank you so much.  I didn't mention this before but yes, the code up there is running in a simple, does nothing, console app - just that bit of code is what I am executing.  Rene, I placed it in the try/catch to see if there was an exception being thrown but nothing is caught.  Removing the try/catch produced the same behavior - it hits the line mentioned and then acts as if the end of the code has been reached.  Could it be permission related?  I'm trying to read Chrome browser history.  The actual SELECT is: select * from urls order by last_visit_time desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
Can have bad stuff in the pipe messing up things

```
finally () 
{
   command.Cancel(); // !!!
   reader.Dispose();
}
```

Reader is pretty efficient as it will get a block of data at a time.
So what can happen is the database can throw an error on a row you have not even actually read.
Not saying that is what is going on here but could be.
Set order by asc and then desc and see if that changes stuff.
And with (nolock).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Blam.  I added a "finally" but it never made it to the command.Cancel().

Comment: Try it in the catch.  If that does not work I will delete my answer.

Comment: Blam, I don't know if this was the actual fix here or not - but it caused me to let my code run longer than I have been.  I assumed the code was just exiting, but it wasn't.  It was sitting there for a good bit before finally returning me with a message that indicated the database was locked.  I'm sorry I didn't do this earlier...now I just need to research why it is locked.

Comment: I would catch the database specific exception as it will typically have more detail.  Don't know about SQLLite but in SQL there is a with (nolock).  In production with (nolock) may not be acceptable but it would if that fixes it then an indication of locking.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had this issue recently and nothing I've seen was able to fix it.
I had, as above,

```
while
(reader.read) do some stuff
```

Everytime I tried to run this it would just break out, with no error.

Eventually I set a boolean = reader.read to see what the value was. It was true. So why the hell is it not reading? just for the lols I set the while condition to be:

```
dim b as boolean = reader.read
while (b) do some stuff
```

This then worked. So it seems I have to set the value of reader.read and then reference that.  B is then set to false after some stuff is done.

This seems like something that shouldn't have to be done but it works....